# how do you fill in a shape on python version 2.7.5 in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, shapes

On python 2.7.5 pygame, how do you fill in a shape you have created by drawing individual lines, or is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way if the lines meet at their points(you don't have crazy intersections). Just simply use a polygon:

```
  pygame.draw.polygon(Surface, color, pointlist, width=0)
```

Here's a link to the documentation:

[Pygame Polygon](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.polygon)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily does this with any shape using the `pygame.draw`method by just setting the width to 0

for example:

```
pygame.draw.circle(Surface, color, pos, radius, width=0)
```

so you adjust the size using the `radius` parameter thneyou can change the width but if you want the shape to fill set the `width` to 0

this is the same with any shape you draw

anymore questions just read [here!](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html)